# Live sharing Nodejs and Visual studio

Tags: node.js, authentication, visual-studio-code, live-streaming, visual-studio-liveshare

We run visual studio code as a container in our Nodejs project. I want to implement live sharing for team members on vs code which is run in project.

Is there an open source tools for this propose?
and

How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with what is built-in to VS Code?

Comment: Users. For using built-in vs code sharing we should login with github or microsoft account but i need to users login with our application accounts. In our application we have users and we want to users login to vs code sharing with those account not others. I don't know is it possible with vs code?

Comment: So, you want to use VS Code Live Share, but with your own custom login?

Comment: If it is possible yes. .